# Display two linked values for two id field pointing the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

In my PostgreSQL database I have a table like this one:

```
id|link1|link2|
---------------
1 | 34  | 66
2 | 23  | 8
3 | 11  | 99
```

`link1` and `link2` fields are both pointing to the same table `table2` which has `id` and `descr` fields.

I would make an SQL query that returns the same row the `id` and the `descr` value for the two field like this:

```
id|link1|link2|desc_l1|desc_l2|
-------------------------------
1 | 34  |66  | bla  | sisusj|
2 | 23  | 8  | ghhj | yui   |
3 | 11  | 99 | erd  |  bnbn |
```

I've try different queries, but everyone returns two rows per `id` instead of one.
How can I achieve these results in my PostgreSQL 9.04 database?

Comment: Could you post one of your query that return 2 rows per id?

Comment: Update your question to include the queries that you have attempted so we can see where you may have made an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, this query should work for you. Assume your first table name's table_name.

```
SELECT t.id, t.link1, t.link2, 
    l1.descr AS desc_l1,
    l2.descr AS desc_l2
FROM table_name t 
LEFT JOIN table2 l1
ON t.link1 = l1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 l2
ON t.link2 = l2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case here Like:

```
select link1,link2,
case
 when link1='34' and link2='66' then 'bla'
  when link1='23' and link2='8' then 'ghs'
   when link1='11' and link2='99' then 'erd'
end as desc_li,
case
 when link1='34' and link2='66' then 'sjm'
   when link1='23' and link2='8' then 'yur'
   when link1='11' and link2='99' then 'bnn'
end as desc_l2

from table1
```